# unable to show a record on fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

I have created a web api using ASP.net and C# connecting to an external SQL Server 2012. My connection string is `myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=./PALLAVI-PC/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";`

There seems to be no error in the code. But when I deploy the service and try to extract a record on fiddler, I am getting a 404 error. The GET url is `localhost:xxxxx/api/student/1`

Am posting the code below:

StudentController.cs

```
   //api/student/id
    [HttpGet]
     [ActionName("GetStudentByID")]
    public Student Get(int id)
    {
        //SQL Reader
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        //SQL Connection class
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();

        //creating the connection string            
        myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=./PALLAVI-PC/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";

        //SQL Commands class
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        //sql query
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from Students where Roll_Number=" + id + ";";

        sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;

        //opening the connection
        myConnection.Open();

        //extracting the record
        reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        //object of class student
        Student myStudent = null;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            myStudent = new Student();
            myStudent.Roll_Number = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
            myStudent.FirstName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            myStudent.LastName = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            myStudent.Class = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3));
            myStudent.Gender = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
        }

        return myStudent;

        //close connection
        myConnection.Close();


    }
```

if I change the slash to forward in connectionstring, I am getting an error `unrecognized character`.

Comment: Try to access `localhost:xxxxx/api/student/Get/1` or `localhost:xxxxx/api/student/GetStudentByID/1`

Comment: Your 404 error has nothing to do with the DB connection (or connection string), so focus on why your URL doesn't resolve to anything first. Check IIS settings to ensure your site is mapped to the correct directory containing your code. check the bindings to make sure your port usage is correct. Maybe try putting some sample html files in each directory to give you an idea as to whether you can request those correctly before looking at your web api method. Also, check try your requests with http and https too. Again, your IIS settings will help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your connection string as 
`myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=PALLAVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";`